# Creating a new desktop on one monitor creates a desktop on all monitors

Tags: keyboard, display, desktop

Additionally shifting my desktop on the one monitor I created (with 2 monitors plugged into my MacBook Pro) shifts every desktop. I don't want this feature how do I turn it off?

I just want to be able to create one desktop on one monitor and keep all the rest of my monitors desktops the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate spaces.

[image]

Comment: Also, I believe you have to log out or reboot for this change to take effect.

Comment: ah, useful info. I admit I switched that off the first day the pref appeared on Mavericks[?] & will not touch it again - it really messed up my working method ;-)